# Should all AD USNs be the same?

Tags: active-directory

I have two AD sites, one with 5 DCs and the other with 2 DCs. I'm seeing most DCs with zero difference between current and original USNs, and only two (on the same site) showing any difference. Is this to be expected?

My thought is that all should see a difference because every DC should see replication and therefore updates should be made on every DC - or do the USNs only change if an update has been made on the respective DC?

Comment: What command are you using to view your domain controllers' USNs?  And are any of them RODCs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good, very long article on Technet that you could probably benefit from reading, titled, [*How the Active Directory Replication Model Works*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772726%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), but in short , it's exceedingly improbable that any two DCs in a forest will have the same USN at the same time, as the DC USN is incremented each time an Active Directory object is changed on that DC.  As such, I seriously doubt you're actually seeing the same USN on a number of DCs, but more likely the originating USN value for the last replicated change, or perhaps the [High-watermark (direct up-to-dateness vector) value](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961798.aspx).

Having said that, the Microsoft documentation specifically states that you shouldn't concern yourself with USNs unless you're having replication issues such as a [potential USN rollback](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/875495/en-us).  But, if you'd like to anyway, run [`Repadmin /showutdvec`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742023.aspx) against all your domain controllers and view the local USN reported back from each domain controller.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. Normally I wouldn't be looking at such details, but I've been told the domain has replication issues (not seen them myself yet). I saw these USN values whilst using AD Sites & Services and am probably just confusing myself. Some of the DCs show USNs of a few thousand, whilst others are up in the millions. I'm just wondering if the USNs get updated on receipt of replication data, or only when updates are made on the specific DC?

Comment: @Lowell The local DC USN is incremented only when a change is made on that DC, yes.  To give you some persepctive, we have a couple dozen DCs, and their local USN values range from 21416 to 63937999, so a large range in DC USN values is generally pretty normal.  It's much less likely that all your DCs would have close USN values, in fact.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I thought it a bit strange that the USNs could be that different and for us not to see bigger issues!